# OVS Flows - Ping working, other traffic not

Tags: networking, openflow, openvswitch

Could someone kindly explain why the following flow config (these flows are the only flows on the bridge) does not work as expected ?

I can ping the hosts on each side, but other traffic (e.g. web/ssh etc. does not pass).

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow xl1 dl_type=0x800,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.1.0/24,actions=output:73
ovs-ofctl add-flow xl1 dl_type=0x800,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.2.0/24,actions=output:76
ovs-ofctl add-flow xl1 arp,nw_dst=10.2.1.0/24,actions=output:73
ovs-ofctl add-flow xl1 arp,nw_dst=10.2.2.0/24,actions=output:76
```

The traces certainly seem to suggest the traffic should pass:

```
ovs-appctl ofproto/trace xl1 in_port=73,tcp,nw_src=10.
2.1.1,nw_dst=10.2.2.1,tcp_dst=22
Bridge: xl1
Flow: tcp,metadata=0,in_port=73,vlan_tci=0x0000,dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:00,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:00,nw_src=10.2.1.1,nw_dst=10.2.2.1,nw_tos=0,nw_ecn=0,nw_ttl=0,tp_src=0,tp_dst=22,tcp_flags=0x000
Rule: table=0 cookie=0 ip,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.2.0/24
OpenFlow actions=output:76

Final flow: unchanged
Megaflow: skb_priority=0,ip,in_port=73,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.2.1,nw_frag=no
Datapath actions: 76

ovs-appctl ofproto/trace xl1 in_port=76,tcp,nw_src=10.
2.2.1,nw_dst=10.2.1.1,tcp_dst=22
Bridge: xl1
Flow: tcp,metadata=0,in_port=76,vlan_tci=0x0000,dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:00,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:00,nw_src=10.2.2.1,nw_dst=10.2.1.1,nw_tos=0,nw_ecn=0,nw_ttl=0,tp_src=0,tp_dst=22,tcp_flags=0x000
Rule: table=0 cookie=0 ip,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.1.0/24
OpenFlow actions=output:73

Final flow: unchanged
Megaflow: skb_priority=0,ip,in_port=76,nw_src=10.2.0.0/20,nw_dst=10.2.1.1,nw_frag=no
Datapath actions: 73
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that,
10.2.1.0/24 and 10.2.2.0/24 are not in the same network.
So, if a host, like 10.10.1.1 is looking for 2.0. It may not send out an arp for 2.0. It may send out an arp for its own gateway in the 1.0 network.
You can use this command:

> arp -n

on the hosts on 1.0 network to look into the arp table of these hosts.
You can also use:

> tcpdump -i "eth-name"

on the openvSwitch to see what you can get if you are sending out a non-icmp packet on 1.0 or 2.0 network.

Comment: 10.2.1.0/24 and 10.2.2.0/24 not in 10.2.0.0/20 ? That's news to me !   But never mind, I found the solution.